# Check multiple keys in a dictionary for existence and value

Tags: python

I would like to do something only if an object has two keys with given values:

```
tel = ...
nam = ...
for obj in listofobjs:
    for key, val in obj.items():
        if (key == 'tel' and val == tel) and \
           (key == 'nam' and val == name):
            # do something...
```

Which won't work since key and value can't be two values at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it without having to use `.items()`:

```
for obj in listofobjs:
    if 'tel' in obj and 'nam' in obj and obj['tel']==tel and obj['nam']==nam:
        ...
```

Or you could [*ask for forgiveness*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) provided all dictionary access in the `if` block are *safe*:

```
 for obj in listofobjs:
    try:
        if obj['tel']==tel and obj['nam']==nam:
            ...
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: This does two more dictionary lookups than you need.

Comment: We may choose correctness over small efficiency tweaks :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop over the `.items()` to do this.

```
for obj in listofobjs:
    if (obj.get('tel', None) == tel) and (obj.get('nam', None) == nam):
```

Just use [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to get the key, so that you don't get a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist.

`.get` returns `None` by default, but I'm specifying it here to highlight the ability to use a different default value. If you want to use `None` as the default, you can leave out the second parameter from the `.get` call.

Replace `None` with a value that you know will never be a valid value for `tel` or `nam`.

Comment: This would fail if `tel` and `nam` are the same as the defaults returned by `.get` and the keys are not in the dictionary

Comment: On another note `.get` already returns a default `None`, no need to specify

Comment: You can create a sentinel object if you need to, but most of the time, `None` will work as a valid default value.

Comment: I'm using `None` there to highlight that the default value can be changed.

Comment: you don't need parenthesis around obj.get and get returns None by default so  just obj.get('tel')

Comment: @Alex I highlighted in the answer why I'm keeping the `None`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp you still don't need parenthesis. Also, your solution is not really correct. You don't check for key being in object. So e.g if tel is None and obj is {'name': 'blah'} it will pass your condition. While author wants also to check if key in dictionary. You only check that returned value is the same as variable. Which is incorrect.

Comment: @Alex "Replace None with a value that you know will never be a valid value for tel or nam.". "You can create a sentinel object if you need to, but most of the time, None will work as a valid default value.". This is the idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: @FXAMN No problem, glad I could help.